# Error in CI: act(...) is not supported in production builds of React

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, cicd

Getting an error on CI when running `jest --coverage`

```
act(...) is not supported in production builds of React.
      80 |   describe('sample test', () => {
      81 |     it('sample', () => {
    > 82 |       component = render(<SampleComponent />);
         |                   ^
```

Using:

```
"@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
"jest": "26.6.3",
"jest-environment-jsdom": "26.6.2",
"jest-environment-jsdom-global": "2.0.4",
```

I don't understand why `react-testing-library` does not support testing on production. I can't seem to find anything on this.

Answer (score 2):

You can prefix the script that runs jest with NODE_ENV, for example:

`env NODE_ENV=test jest --ci`

Your CICD process is just triggering the error because the environment variable is set to production. Not actually because the files themselves were compiled in production mode.